# Excel not Visible

Tags: c#, excel-interop, import-from-excel

I am opening an existing Excel file with following process:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

excel.Visible = true;
Workbook w = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"E:\ishu\Test.xlsx"
                                 , Type.Missing,
                                 true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                 Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                 Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                 Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                 Type.Missing);

Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)w.Worksheets[1];

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = ws.UsedRange;
excel.Visible = true;
```

Excel process gets started in task manager but no Excel window get visible.

Comment: Windows Version? Do you click somewhere while Excel starts up?

Comment: Do you run excel from your application code or from some background service (task scheduler)?

Comment: @Arvo Ishu seems to try to open the excel from the application code (via the interop classes as far as I understand the example code

Comment: @ishu Window Server 2003 Enterprise edition SP2

Comment: Do you see any excell process in task manager?

Comment: @RPC wHEN i RUN MY CODE EXCEL.EXE GET STARTED in Task Manager

Comment: Is this definitely running under your account? When you see Excel.exe in the Task Manager is it your username that it's running with?

Comment: @Nanhydrin it is running from my account

Comment: Like @Arvo asked: in what context does this code run? Is it a desktop application, Windows Service or web application?

Comment: Try to put the Excel.WindowState  to xlMaximized (something like this) at the end of your code.

Comment: @Arvo Code is running in VS2008--> New--> Website--> DynamicsAxApplication template, which is generally used to develop web parts for Share Point

Comment: @SergioR I already tried it but no change

Comment: check out this link. hope it helps.  http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-open-excel.htm

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the answer you are looking for, but my application uses

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ExcelFileToOpen);
```

The above is run only when the Excel file exists.